# $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a continuous bijection.$X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces and $f$ is linear

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be arbitrary topological spaces and let $f:X\rightarrow Y$  be a continuous bijection.$X$ and $Y$  are Banach spaces and $f$ is linear.To show $f$ is a homeomorphism.How to show $f$ and $f^{-1}$ both are continuous?

Comment: Can you use the [bounded inverse theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_inverse_theorem)? Or, equivalently, can you use the [open mapping theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_%28functional_analysis%29)?

Comment: I have not learnt that theorem yet.But I saw it from the link.It's now clear why $f^{-1}$ is cont.Thanks @Omnomnomnom

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $f:X\to Y$ is bounded linear map and bijective.

**Claim:** $f^{-1}:Y\to X$ also continuous...
let $G$ open in $X$
 then $$f^{-1}(G)=\{y\in Y: f^{-1}(x)=y,x\in G\}$$
$$=\{y\in Y: f(x)=y,x\in G\}$$
$$=f(G)\text{  since f is one one}$$
  the will follow because $f$ is a open map.

Comment: Could you double check this. You say let $G$ be open in $X$ and then consider $f^{-1}(G)$, but $f^{-1} : Y \to X$. Shouldn't you have considered $\big(f^{-1}\big)^{-1}$?